# What latitude / longitude combination will produce a negative geohash integer?

Tags: go, geolocation, amazon-dynamodb, geospatial, geohashing

I'm trying to write a simple go application that interfaces with DynamoDB to store points as a geohash.

Essentially I'm trying to replicate what the [Java geo lib for DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/geo-library-for-amazon-dynamodb-part-1-table-structure/) does, but with Go.

I'm using https://github.com/mmcloughlin/geohash to encode the point:

```
geohash.EncodeInt(47.61121, -122.31846) // produces 6379143490183141059
```

The Geo Library for Amazon DynamoDB [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/geo-library-for-amazon-dynamodb-part-1-table-structure/) post mentions that a negative 64-bit geohash encoding of a point is possible.  Specifically they mention `-6093522776912656819`.

I can't find a lat/lng combination, that when run through `geohash.EncodeInt()` produces a negative integer value.

What lat/lng combination will encode to a negative integer?

Comment: My hunch is the go port of the S2 lib (https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/geo/s2#CellID) can't return a negative int, because it returns `uint64`. The Java port of S2 returns a `float`, which can produce negative. If I use go S2 port, I can just assume positive integers always. AMIRITE?

Comment: I couldn't find any! Geohash Wikipedia entry mentions some edge cases but none of them will produce negative values. Your hunch is most probably correct.